# Development Junit test notification

Tags: java, junit

I'm in the development phase of a Test class to test send notifications :

1- SMS  (send SMS using phone number )

2- Email (send email )

3- WebSocket (send websocket )

This is the first time I have used Junit. It's working but I need a check of the quality of code. My project is a spring boot application rest API.

the below code test Class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(NotificationController.class)
@Import(TestConfigForMail.class)
@ActiveProfiles("local")
public class NotificationTest  {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private SpanAccessor tracer;


    /**
     * test send SMS notification 
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Test
    public void testSMSNotification() throws Exception {
        Notifications notification=new Notifications();
        List<GeneralNotificationInfo> listNotifications=new ArrayList<GeneralNotificationInfo>();
        SMSNotification smsNotification=new SMSNotification();
        smsNotification.setTemplateId(1);
        smsNotification.setSmsTo(new String[] {"+10002222"});
        Message message=new Message();
        message.setTitle("HELLO FROM SMSNOTIFICATION TEST");
        message.setBody("HELLO FROM SMSNOTIFICATION TEST");
        smsNotification.setMessage(message);
        listNotifications.add(smsNotification);
        notification.setNotfication(listNotifications);
        ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        this.mockMvc.perform(post(NotificationURI_Constants.SEND_NOTFICATION).contentType(
                MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(ow.writeValueAsString(notification)))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.result.status.SMSNotification", is("TRUE")));

    }

    /**
     * test Email Notification
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Test
    public void testEmailNotification() throws Exception {
        Notifications notification=new Notifications();
        List<GeneralNotificationInfo> listNotifications=new ArrayList<GeneralNotificationInfo>();

        EmailNotification emailNotification=new EmailNotification();
        emailNotification.setTemplateId(1);
        emailNotification.setEmail(new String[] {"test@yahoo.com"});
        Message messageEmail=new Message();
        messageEmail.setTitle("HELLO EMAIL NOTIFICATION FROM TEST");
        messageEmail.setBody("HELLO EMAIL NOTIFICATION FROM TEST BODY");
        emailNotification.setMessage(messageEmail);
        listNotifications.add(emailNotification);

        notification.setNotfication(listNotifications);
        ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        this.mockMvc.perform(post(NotificationURI_Constants.SEND_NOTFICATION).contentType(
                MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(ow.writeValueAsString(notification)))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.result.status.EmailNotification", is("TRUE")));

    }


    /**
     * test Web Socket Notification 
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Test
    public void testWebSocketNotification() throws Exception {
        Notifications notification=new Notifications();
        List<GeneralNotificationInfo> listNotifications=new ArrayList<GeneralNotificationInfo>();

        WebSocketNotification  webSocketNotification=new WebSocketNotification();
        webSocketNotification.setTemplateId(1);
        webSocketNotification.setUsersID(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"john"}));
        Message messageEmail=new Message();
        messageEmail.setTitle("HELLO WEBSOCKET NOTIFICATION FROM TEST");
        messageEmail.setBody("HELLO WEBSOCKET NOTIFICATION FROM TEST BODY");
        webSocketNotification.setMessage(messageEmail);
        listNotifications.add(webSocketNotification);

        notification.setNotfication(listNotifications);
        ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        this.mockMvc.perform(post(NotificationURI_Constants.SEND_NOTFICATION).contentType(
                MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(ow.writeValueAsString(notification)))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.result.status.WebSocketNotification", is("TRUE")));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few small tweaks that can improve the readability of your code:

- Your code could really benefit from a few strategically placed white 
  spaces.
- Instead of instantiating objects at the start of a method and
  forgetting about them for 5+ lines, try creating your objects only
  when you must. Same idea applies when storing primitive types.
- Be consistent with the spaces between your assignment operators.

Bringing the above ideas together might look something like this:

```
@Test
public void testSMSNotification() throws Exception {
    Message message = new Message();
    message.setTitle("HELLO FROM SMSNOTIFICATION TEST");
    message.setBody("HELLO FROM SMSNOTIFICATION TEST");

    SMSNotification smsNotification = new SMSNotification();
    smsNotification.setTemplateId(1);
    smsNotification.setSmsTo(new String[] {"+10002222"});
    smsNotification.setMessage(message);

    List<GeneralNotificationInfo> listNotifications = new ArrayList<GeneralNotificationInfo>();
    listNotifications.add(smsNotification);

    Notifications notification = new Notifications();
    notification.setNotfication(listNotifications);

    ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    this.mockMvc.perform(post(NotificationURI_Constants.SEND_NOTFICATION).contentType(
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(ow.writeValueAsString(notification)))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.result.status.SMSNotification", is("TRUE")));
}
```